How thick should aluminium plate be to support a person of upto 100 kg as a door step support into an RV?
I wish to fit a proprietary external slide-out step to my motorhome/RV. The issue I have is that I need to fabricate a U shaped box to fit outside under the existing internal GRP step to do this.  A bit like this:  [_]  (two pieces of C channel and a plate supported by the bottom angles of the C channel). I can source extruded C channel and aluminium plate in various thicknesses, but which is right?
The C channel I would need to use to give the correct clearance below the GRP step is 7 inch (drop) x 3 inch (angled sides) the 7 inch part is 3/8" thick and the angle sides are 1/2" thick.  The C channel would be 310mm long. The plate needs to be 700mm long by 310mm wide, it will be supported on the C channel with 50mm of plate resting on the channel at each end.  The proprietary step has four fixings which are 465mm apart on the long direction and 250mm in the short direction.  There is very little room under the GRP step so using angled aluminium for rigidity is not possible.
Everything would be bolted together with M8 nuts and bolts and probably bonded with some adhesive.  Any help much appreciated, thank you.
